# Cucumber step definitions in .feature file not highlight

Tags: automated-testing, cucumber, maven, intellij

In my project, I create simple feature file in my maven project using cucumber syntax.

[image: Login.feature file]

but IntelliJ IDEA, not highlight steps in feature file and also I cant use ALT+ENTER key to create step definition

I added the cucumber-java dependencies and also installed the Gherkin and cucumber plugins, but still feature files aren't recognized as they should be. What could be the problem?

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: Nope, no any error message

Comment: Getting "No Definition found" for each steps in Feature file however i have mentioned glue of these steps in Step Definition file. Working on eclipse. Please help me out with this issue.
-Sonal

Answer (score 2):

**Solved**

File --> Settings--> Editor --> Inspection And

Check all the options in Cucumber like following

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the TestRunner.java file. I added the following code: "stepNotifications = true"

package cucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
features="src/test/java/features/Login.feature",
glue="stepDefinations",
stepNotifications = true)
public class TestRunner {

}

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I too get same problem when tried to create from the scratch. I have found this solution

1. go to file
2. then click settings
3. then click File Types
4. then find Cucumber Scenario and enter *.feature in Registered pattern

Hope this helps....